# 100000 objects: How to autocomplete in an NSTextField fast

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, autocomplete, nstextfield

I need to autocomplete the user's entries in an NSTextField and I use an NSArray to check if there is a match but the NSArray is about 100,000 objects so the matching takes a noticeable time.

The way I implemented this feature is more or less the same way like it's suggested here:

[Autocomplete with twitter usernames in text field (cocoa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637860/autocomplete-with-twitter-usernames-in-text-field-cocoa)

Is there a way to make things faster? Does anyone know a better way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should add example of how you are handling **completionsForPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:** This way people can make suggestions.  Also, where are you reading these 100,000 names from?

Comment: The strings are read from a file into an array.

Answer (score 4):

I have a class I wrote just for that called [NDTrie](http://github.com/nathanday/ndtrie) (and [NDMutableTrie](http://github.com/nathanday/ndtrie)), it's basicly a tree structure where the key for a node is the string all of its children begin with, it makes search for all words that begin with 'cat' for example quick because you just have to find the node for the key 'cat' and the enumerate over it and all of its children. As well as holding strings it can also hold any object.

Answer (score 2):

A comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960700/893113) linked to a Github repo for [PJTernarySearchTree](https://github.com/peakji/PJTernarySearchTree). You could give that a try.